# How to install Ubuntu 13.04 or later on Dell inspiron 17 and remove windows 8

Tags: windows-8

For my personal work purpose, I bought Dell inspiron 17 and at that time I did not know that I will not be able to install Ubuntu on my laptop.

Please share how can I uninstall windows 8 and install Ubuntu OS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the [standard Ubuntu installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall), and at the "`Installation type`" step, choose 
`Erase disk and install Ubuntu` (2nd option on the screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: thanks. I was able to install ubuntu along with Windwos 8.